# How can I calculate all possible combinations between a specific ratio range?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, ratio, image-processing

Not sure this is the right wording for this sort of problem, but let me explain by context.

Instagram displays specific image ratios when posted to a feed. These ratios are:

> 1:1 (square)
>
> 1.91:1 (landscape/horizontal)
>
> 4:5 (portrait/vertical)

On the company's help forum, they also state:

> [...] the photo's aspect ratio is **between** 1.91:1 and 4:5 [...]

This specific wording makes it seem like there are other acceptable image proportions in their platform. What I want to do is test this hypothesis by posting other aspect rations that lie between *1.91:1* and *4:5*. I know for a fact that *3:2*-sized images works.

Is there a formula, trick or correct way to calculate or generate all possible `whole values` between these two ratios?

Comment: What do you mean by "whole values"? Is $2:3$ a whole value?

Comment: One option is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, I'd consider that a "whole value". Not sure if it's the right nomenclature, though. I only added this part because the rules state to not ask questions with too many possibilities.

Comment: Well, there are still infinitely many "whole" values between $1.91:1$ and $4:5$, so there is no way to generate "all" of them. You will need to narrow this down some more if you want your question to be answerable.

Comment: @PM2Ring After a quick look, it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, BUT only for values between 0:1 and 1:1. I wonder if I'll find anything closer to what I want or a way to apply the method from the Farey Sequence.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I see. Maybe another way of looking at the ratios is to use them as fractions. Example: "How to find all possible fractions between 1.91/1 and 4/5", but with some kind of limitation like in "increments of 0.5". I'm just babbling at this point.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm gonna look into this a bit more to try to understand it better. So many different terms I don't understand. And that was a typo! I meant 3:2 (Width:Height).

Comment: Check this live [Python Farey sequence script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFT03OgjAQ3XOKF92AVkmNLiTBeAHdfN8FSltio1RTazQh3t0ZCDCbmb6f6byj89EGpWNibI1GOZ_6Um6yIgGVRwkSpD5LuvccJ-dd82qgng-rI4KK7t5RSqAi9VZgN2j_rL57A9rfdEgkPvVYQWbIc9IxqAUM-7AgfglJ_mHs97wv7mbxH162v4krkEMjhxmRR-A761mri82XmNZwL9GGYr39zrJR6GpyH0rI9V5OC7mqYNV1ROY420-cjue69gGWqLoA0-8cXgxRuAnSLujEFVM8GhqrH2CQUro=&lang=python). `n` sets the maximum denominator.

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the desired sequence of ratios using a [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence):

> the Farey sequence of order $n$ is the sequence of completely reduced fractions, either between 0 and 1, or without this restriction, which when in lowest terms have denominators less than or equal to $n$, arranged in order of increasing size.

That article shows a simple algorithm to produce the next term of the Farey sequence of order $n$ from the previous two terms. That algorithm starts at $0/1$, but we can adapt it to start from $4/5$.

One important property of any Farey sequence is that given two adjacent terms $a/b, c/d$ (with $a/b < c/d$), then $c/d - a/b = 1 / bd$. We can use that to find the next term after $4/5$.

Let $a/b = 4/5$.
Thus
$$c/d - 4/5 = 1/5d$$
$$5c - 4d = 1$$

Now, for any $t$,
$$5(1+4t) - 4(1+5t) = 1$$
So we can set
$$c=1+4t$$
$$d=1+5t$$
for some suitable $t$. It can be shown that the resulting $c, d$ are coprime, so $c/d$ is a fraction in lowest terms.

We choose $t$ such that the resulting $d$ is as large as possible with $d\le n$.
That is,
$$d = 1+5t \le n$$
So
$$t=\lfloor(n-1)/5\rfloor$$

---

Here's some Python code (derived from the Wikipedia example) which implements this algorithm. It uses a Sage feature to read the input parameter $n$, but it can be easily adapted to use the standard Python procedures for getting input data.

```
# Partial Farey sequence. PM 2Ring 2021.09.15
# See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4250558/207316
@interact
def main(n=12):
    n = int(n)

    # Minimum aspect ratio
    a, b = 4, 5

    # Second term
    t = (n - 1) // 5
    c, d = 4 * t + 1, 5 * t + 1

    while True:
        r = c / d
        print(f"{c:2} / {d:2} = {r:.4}")
        if r >= 1.91:
            break
        # Next term
        k = (n + b) // d
        a, b, c, d = c, d, k * c - a, k * d - b
```

Here's the output for $n=12$:

```
 9 / 11 = 0.8182
 5 /  6 = 0.8333
 6 /  7 = 0.8571
 7 /  8 = 0.875
 8 /  9 = 0.8889
 9 / 10 = 0.9
10 / 11 = 0.9091
11 / 12 = 0.9167
 1 /  1 = 1.0
13 / 12 = 1.083
12 / 11 = 1.091
11 / 10 = 1.1
10 /  9 = 1.111
 9 /  8 = 1.125
 8 /  7 = 1.143
 7 /  6 = 1.167
13 / 11 = 1.182
 6 /  5 = 1.2
11 /  9 = 1.222
 5 /  4 = 1.25
14 / 11 = 1.273
 9 /  7 = 1.286
13 / 10 = 1.3
 4 /  3 = 1.333
15 / 11 = 1.364
11 /  8 = 1.375
 7 /  5 = 1.4
17 / 12 = 1.417
10 /  7 = 1.429
13 /  9 = 1.444
16 / 11 = 1.455
 3 /  2 = 1.5
17 / 11 = 1.545
14 /  9 = 1.556
11 /  7 = 1.571
19 / 12 = 1.583
 8 /  5 = 1.6
13 /  8 = 1.625
18 / 11 = 1.636
 5 /  3 = 1.667
17 / 10 = 1.7
12 /  7 = 1.714
19 / 11 = 1.727
 7 /  4 = 1.75
16 /  9 = 1.778
 9 /  5 = 1.8
20 / 11 = 1.818
11 /  6 = 1.833
13 /  7 = 1.857
15 /  8 = 1.875
17 /  9 = 1.889
19 / 10 = 1.9
21 / 11 = 1.909
23 / 12 = 1.917
```

And here's a link to a [live version of the script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFT8tuwjAQvOcrRuRCIMRxStoSKVVPvVGhwg84zkIsiAHHqFSIf68dBOxl1_NY74RYCGOV2OFLGPpDR8cTaUkJFnNkP0pvkKUZT9JZwvMgxJIIjbWHrmCsFbZJOivkls6yEXpDidy37MimWZ7m-TvL0rcX_hp8Km3JCGmDmtZohdJDXfIsKgK40ijhBEMdBf07xFxp1Z5aiO5A0sIIq_Y9JWJUTj2Nkd-1S5J7XcPtb3vEOn6oMQGPwJjTeVDGqL0PI8ePwZ3_Pt72_DZqR1iZE91u8mWcQ4KhfiAH4-9cDy6yyK6OudS-l7iYIpleB9FDqNbO_VGCJzP-XOirMiS2DyTEN53t83hf21uAMao-wPN3Hz6-R_EtdtqRO3HiKT_Wbqz-AXT5cNI=&lang=python), which runs on the SageMathCell server.